# Reference Request: Where can I read about philosophy of the digital arts?

Tags: reference-request, aesthetics

I am interested in reading about ways to evaluate art that are done solely by computers (computer generated art) or otherwise by the help of computers or by the usage of computers such as in digital painting. What philosophical sources could be  of help to me?

Comment: See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/digital-art/ - the article might be broader than what you're looking for and not focused on evaluation of digital art nor on digital painting. But it might serve you well for introductory general overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome Luna

One article which might be of help is **Christiane Paul**'s 'Renderngs of Digital Art', Leonardo, Vol. 35, No. 5, Tenth Anniversary New York Digital Salon (2002), pp.
471-474+476-484. The Abstract will make clear whether it is what you want:

> This essay identifies the current qualifier of choice,
>    "new media," by explaining how this term is used
>    to describe digital art in various forms. Establish-
>    ing a historical context, the author highlights the
>    pioneer exhibitions and artists who began working
>    with new technology and digital art as early as the
>    late 196os and early 197os. The article proceeds to
>    articulate the shapes and forms of digital art,
>    recognizing its broad range of artistic practice:
>    music, interactive installation, installation with net-
>    work components, software art, and purely
>    Internet-based art. The author examines the
>    themes and narratives specific to her selection of
>    artwork, specifically interactive digital installations
>    and net art. By addressing these forms, the author
>    illustrates the hybrid nature of this medium and the
>    future of this art practice.

She also has a book: Digital Art, ISBN 10: 0500203679 / ISBN 13: 9780500203675
Published by Thames & Hudson, 2003.

Or perhaps **Paul Crowther** promises more of what you want:

> ... many new media works combine visual, written, and audio material in ways
>    that obliterate traditional boundaries between art
>    forms. However, many other such works maintain
>    a primarily visual emphasis. These will be the focus of my analysis. I will concentrate specifically
>    on key points of interface and difference between
>    the traditional idioms and those visually orientated images and configurations that are computer  generated or depend upon computer technology for
>    their full visual realization.
>    It is common practice nowadays to use the
>    term 'digital art' in relation to such computer-
>    dependent visual idioms.7 1 will follow this usage.
>    Text-based works will only figure in the analysis
>    insofar as they emphasize the text qua visual.
>
> Digital art centers on electronically based tech-
>    nology utilizing mathematical algorithms for the
>    acquisition, storage, processing, and presentation
>    of information. The information in question is often realized in a visual format (rather than through
>    text or numbers alone) and can consist of gener-
>    ated material (based on mathematical formulae or
>    "painted" using bodily held instruments and dedicated hardware) or of information derived from a
>    scanned source (including already existing images
>    that have been converted to a format readable via
>    the appropriate hardware). (Paul Crowther, 'Ontology and Aesthetics of Digital Art',  The Journal of Aesthetics and Art Criticism, Vol. 66, No. 2 (Spring, 2008), pp. 161-
>   170: 162.)

Answer (score 2):

Further scholarly sources (books and papers) that might be helpful:

**New Philosophy for New Media** by Mark B. N. Hansen

**A Philosophy of Computer Art** by Dominic McIver Lopes

**Digital Art and Meaning**: reading kinetic poetry, text machines, mapping art, and interactive installations, By Roberto Simanowski

**Authenticity and computer art** by Margaret A. Boden

**A framework for understanding generative art**, By Alan Dorin ,Jonathan McCabe,Jon McCormack, Gordon Monro & Mitchell Whitelaw

**What is generative art?** By Margaret A. Boden &Ernest A. Edmonds